# getting specific dict property values from multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a Dict that looks like so...

```
values = {
      'student': [{
                     'field': 'prefix', 
                     'description': 'First name'
                  }, 
                  {
                     'field': 'suffix', 
                     'description': 'Last name'
                  }, 
                  {
                     'field': 'student_email',
                     'description': 'Email address'
                  }],
      'classes':  [{
                     'field': 'course_code', 
                     'description': 'Course code'
                  }]

    }
```

I'm trying to get

```
['prefix', 'suffix', 'student_email', 'course_code']
```

But I'm trying to do so without loops in loops.

So this is what I have:

```
stored = [] # store the field values in a list
for value in values:
    stored.append(value['field'])
```

And it's throwing:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: May I ask why you need a dictionary containing "field" and "description"? This doesn't seem like an efficient way of using dictionaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the error because the dictionary is one level deeper than your loop, and you can call `items()` on the dictionary to get the values part:

```
[v1['field'] for k, v in values.items() for v1 in v]
# ['prefix', 'suffix', 'student_email', 'course_code']
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to python, but is it cool to use loops in loops like that?

Comment: That is called `list comprehension` and it is very commonly used in python language. so I would say, feel safe to use it.

Comment: @Modelesq It's "cool" when you have no other choice, which you don't because of the structure of your data. Both solutions so far are merely nested for-loops by another name.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to gather those strings in a list but you are not constrained to arrange them in a specific order, this should work:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [x['field'] for x in chain(*values.values())]
['course_code', 'prefix', 'suffix', 'student_email']
```

The core element of the snippet above is the function [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it completely functionally combining, [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

print(list(map(itemgetter("field"), chain.from_iterable(values.values()))))
['course_code', 'prefix', 'suffix', 'student_email']
```